# Cannot get tkinter grid to layout my GUI as I want

Tags: python, tkinter

sorry for the simple question. Relatively new to python and especially Object Oriented and Class systems. Basically, I want my GUI to have a couple of rows across the top of the window (across full width). Beneath, I want 4 equal sized columns. I don't want this to impact my plots (on a different page). Any help is much appreciated. I cannot workout how to use tkinter to get this to work.

Thanks

```
__author__ = "dev"

# https://pythonprogramming.net/object-oriented-programming-crash-course-tkinter/?completed=/tkinter-depth-tutorial-making-actual-program/
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import style
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import matplotlib.dates as mdates

LargeFont = ("Verdana", 16)
style.use("ggplot")

def yfinance_get(index):
    tkr = yf.Ticker(index)

    today = dt.datetime.today().isoformat()
    m_ago = dt.datetime.today() - dt.timedelta(days=30)

    h_px = tkr.history(period="1d", start=m_ago, end=today[:10])

    return h_px


class DailySumm(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # initialise - runs as soon as the class is called
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)  # frame creates the window of our GUI
        container.pack(side="top", expand=True)  # pack is similar to grid, but less accurate
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        # creates an empty dictionary called named self.frames, this will hold the diff "pages" in the Gui

        for f in (StartPage, Equities):  # for each page defined, this tuple needs to be updated to include
            # this loop will add the pages to the self.frames dict
            frame = f(container, self)
            self.frames[f] = frame  # enters a new entry into the dictionary, the StartPage page
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)  # this calls the show_frame method with cont = StartPage

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]  # cont = dict key to frames (dict)
        frame.tkraise()  # this raises the "frame" to the front of the window (i.e. shows it to the user)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):  # this creates the StartPage page which inherits the tk.Frame functionality (ie imports)
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)  # parent is the parent class, in this case DailySumm

        label = tk.Label(self, text="News and Market Data", font=LargeFont).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Equities", font=LargeFont).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Credit", font=LargeFont).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)
        label4 = tk.Label(self, text="Currencies", font=LargeFont).grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)
        label5 = tk.Label(self, text="Commodities", font=LargeFont).grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10)

        button_equ = ttk.Button(self, text="Equities",
                                command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Equities)).grid(row=2, column=0)
        # lambda stops the function being called on inception, only when the button is pressed


class Equities(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Equities", font=LargeFont)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button_home = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                                 command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button_home.pack()

        index = [['FTSE 100', '^FTSE'], ['S&P 500', '^GSPC'], ["Nikkei 225", "^N225"], ["MSCI EM", "EEM"]]
        fig = Figure(dpi=100)

        for i in range(0, 3+1):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i+1)
            plot_data = yfinance_get(index[i][1])
            ax.plot(plot_data['Close'], color='r', label=index[i][0])
            ax.grid(which="major", color='k', linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.3)
            ax.legend(loc=2)
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=mdates.MONDAY))
            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%d-%m"))


        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


app = DailySumm()
app.geometry("2560x1600")
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create a frame for the rows at the top, and another frame to hold the four columns below. You can use `pack` to add these frames to the window, and use `grid` in the lower frame to manage the columns. To get the columns to be the same size you can use the `uniform` option for each column.

Here's an example of the technique:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

top_frame = tk.Frame(bd=1, relief="raised", height=50)
bottom_frame = tk.Frame(bd=1, relief="raised")

top_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")
bottom_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

# add labels to the columns so that we can visualize the columns
labels = (
    tk.Label(bottom_frame, bd=1, relief="raised", text="Column 1", height=8, width=10),
    tk.Label(bottom_frame, bd=1, relief="raised", text="Column 2", height=8, width=10),
    tk.Label(bottom_frame, bd=1, relief="raised", text="Column 3", height=8, width=10),
    tk.Label(bottom_frame, bd=1, relief="raised", text="Column 4", height=8, width=10)
)

# add the labels to the columns.
labels[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", ipadx=4)
labels[1].grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", ipadx=4)
labels[2].grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew", ipadx=4)
labels[3].grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="nsew", ipadx=4)

# allocate all extra horizontal space to each column evenly
# the critical piece is both the weight and uniform options
bottom_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="column")
bottom_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="column")
bottom_frame.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1, uniform="column")
bottom_frame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1, uniform="column")

# allocate all extra vertical space to row 0
bottom_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I thought it was better NOT to mix grid and pack in the same program? But I assume this is allowed in this instance. Could you enlighten me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @John: no, it's definitely fine and arguably a best practice to mix them in the same program. You just can't mix them for two or more widgets that have the same parent.